# jQuery UI menu code is not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI, I have added links to the javascript files (`jquery ui.min`, `jquery-ui.css`) in the (head) section, however when I apply jQuery to the menu (`#shMenu`) - it doesn't render. What are my doing wrong ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src= "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

.highlight{background-color:yellow;
    }

#wrapper {
    width:500px;
    margin:auto;
    }

.ui-menu {
    width:15em;
    }

 #cartDiv {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:5px;
    }

 </style>


<body>

<div id = "wrapper">

<ul id = "shMenu">
    <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Super Heroes</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Hulk</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Batman</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Spider-Man</a></li>
            </li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Thor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Comic Books</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Hulk</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Batman</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Spider-Man</a></li>
            <li><a href = "Javascript:void(0)">Thor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul><br/>  



<div id = "accordion">
<h3>Batman</h3>
<div>
A young Bruce Wayne (Christian Bale) travels to the Far East,
where he's trained in the martial arts by Henri Ducard (Liam Neeson),
a member of the mysterious League of Shadows. When Ducard reveals the League's true purpose
-- the complete destruction of Gotham City -- Wayne returns to Gotham intent on cleaning up the city without resorting to murder.
With the help of Alfred (Michael Caine), his loyal butler, and Lucius Fox (Morgan Freeman),
a tech expert at Wayne Enterprises, Batman is born.
</div>


<h3>Thor</h3>
<div>
As the son of Odin (Anthony Hopkins), king of the Norse gods,
Thor (Chris Hemsworth) will soon inherit the throne of Asgard from his aging
father. However, on the day that he is to be crowned, Thor reacts with brutality when the gods' enemies,
the Frost Giants, enter the palace in violation of their treaty. As punishment, Odin banishes Thor to Earth. While Loki (Tom Hiddleston),
Thor's brother, plots mischief in Asgard,
Thor, now stripped of his powers, faces his greatest threat..
</div>


<h3>SpiderMan</h3>
<div>
"Spider-Man" centers on student Peter Parker (Tobey Maguire) who, 
after being bitten by a genetically-altered spider, gains superhuman
strength and the spider-like ability to cling to any surface. He vows
to use his abilities to fight crime, coming to understand the words of his
beloved Uncle Ben:
"With great power comes great responsibility."
</div>


<div id = "shTabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href = "#ironman">Ironman</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#hulk">Hulk</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#thor">thor</a></li>
    <li><a href = "#spiderman">SpiderMan</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id = "ironman">
A billionaire industrialist and genius inventor, Tony Stark (Robert Downey Jr.),
is conducting weapons tests overseas, but terrorists kidnap him to force him to build a devastating 
weapon. Instead, he builds an armored suit and upends his captors. Returning to America,
Stark refines the suit and uses it to combat crime and terrorism.

</div>

<div id = "hulk">
Eric Bana ("Black Hawk Down") stars as scientist Bruce Banner, 
whose inner demons transform him in the aftermath of a catastrophic experiment;
Jennifer Connelly portrays Betty Ross, whose scientific genius unwittingly helps unleash the Hulk; 
Nick Nolte plays Banner's brilliant father, who passes on a tragic legacy to his son; and Sam Elliott
portrays the commander of a top-secret military research center.

</div>

<div id = "thor">
As the son of Odin (Anthony Hopkins), king of the Norse gods,
Thor (Chris Hemsworth) will soon inherit the throne of Asgard from his aging
father. However, on the day that he is to be crowned, Thor reacts with brutality when the gods' enemies,
the Frost Giants, enter the palace in violation of their treaty. As punishment, Odin banishes Thor to Earth. While Loki (Tom Hiddleston),
Thor's brother, plots mischief in Asgard,
Thor, now stripped of his powers, faces his greatest threat..

</div>

<div id = "spiderman">
"Spider-Man" centers on student Peter Parker (Tobey Maguire) who, 
after being bitten by a genetically-altered spider, gains superhuman
strength and the spider-like ability to cling to any surface. He vows
to use his abilities to fight crime, coming to understand the words of his
beloved Uncle Ben:
"With great power comes great responsibility." 
</div>
<div></br>

<div id = "customDialog" title = "custom Dialog">
<p>A random dialog box that contains important information</p>
</div>

<a href = "Javascript:void(0)" id = "openDialog" title = "Open Dialog Box">Open Dialog</a><br/><br/>



<script type = "text/javascript">

 $('document').ready(function() {
   $("#shMenu").menu({
     position: {
        my: "center top" 
        at: "center bottom"
      };

   });

 });


</script>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Where's you jQuery call ?

Comment: Am working under the "start" theme in jquery ui.I am applying the theme on my menu which is a list labeled "shMenu".The jquery code is the last on the page.

Comment: remove `j` tag. read its description

Comment: A lot of code cleanup must be done. I see you have line like: `</li><a href="Javascript:void(0)">Thor</a></li>` This will not render a `li` since you have the `/` in the start tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax errors in your JQuery code. The code should read:

```
 $('document').ready(function() {
   $("#shMenu").menu({
     position: {
       my: "center top",
       at: "center bottom"
     }
   });
 });
```

See working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3z80bLed/